# Error:some index files failed to download in sudo apt-get update after installing ubuntu 14.1

Tags: apt

I'm new to ubuntu. I just installed the ubuntu 14.1 alongside by windows 10. I've installed 64 bit amd-64(ubuntu). When I try to install Git or Java or any software, I need to enter the command `sudo apt-get update`. but It fetches lot of things and stops in the mid with some errors as I given below

```
    Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/multiverse Translation-en_IN
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/restricted Translation-en_IN
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/universe Translation-en_IN
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/universe Translation-en
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/universe i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/main Translation-en
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/multiverse Translation-en_IN
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/restricted Translation-en_IN
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/universe Translation-en_IN
Ign http://in.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/universe Translation-en
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have saw lot of solutions but nothing works. please help me with the possible solutions. thanks in advance

Comment: You're getting the `404  Not Found` errors because 14.10 is an EOL release that's not supported anymore.

Comment: Please install a newer, supported release like 16.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu Utopic Unicorn is [end of life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases), and not supported any more. It has been EOL for over two years.

The repositories are removed from the mirrors, to save disk space, as no new updates will be added anyway.

The solution is to update to a newer version, either by using the graphical tools, or doing `sudo do-release-upgrade` in a terminal. A good alternative may be to reinstall with a newer version, as this probably will take less time.

If you want a environment supported for a long time, consider the LTS releases, which is supported for five years, versus the regular versions which is supported for 10 months.

To successfully update from Utopic to a current release, edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list`, using your favorite editor as root.

Replace `http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` with `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`. After this is done, run `sudo apt-get update`, and then you can try `sudo do-release-upgrade`.

The current LTS, 16.04 is scheduled to become end of life in 2021.

Comment: Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
...                                  
WARNING:root:file 'vivid.tar.gz.gpg' missing
Failed to fetch
Fetching the upgrade failed. There may be a network problem.

Comment: Ok Vidarlo I'll try to update my ubuntu--thanks for your response!

Comment: Yes, you get a warning because the upgrade, Vivid Vervet, is also EOL. And so is the upgrade after that, and after that. This is why a reinstall may be quicker.  You cannot use the normal repositories, you have to use the old-releases.ubuntu.com. Should I expand my answer with this, or do you want to reinstall?

Comment: But after installing 16.04 I won't be getting error related to sudo apt-get update right?. If yes I'll try to install newer one..

Comment: If you install 16.04, it is a LTS release, which will be supported until 2021. You should get no errors doing updates until that time. The next LTS release will be released in 2018, so you'll have 3 years to upgrade to the next LTS before 16.04 is not supported.